# Server Error in '/...' Application

Tags: http, http-status-code-404

I have a website which was built on .Net 2008 , but I upgraded it to .Net 4.0, 
It works correctly, but just for One Page , when I click on the link which target is **Details.aspx** page, this Error occurs:

Server Error in '/...' Application.
HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

which ... Is the name of my application.
Whats this Error? Is it related to Target Framework? because I've already changed it to .net 3.5, but the Error still Remains.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I set <customErrors mode="Off" /> in web.config, but the Error Still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, its because of an Error in VS 2010 IISExpress . I found out that when I run the project using windows installed IIS . I update my VS2010 to VS 2013 express and it works.